# Sliding panels closing when clicked outsite and linking to an open panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am planing to use sliding panels as pages for this [website](http://www.hoveralls.design-way.ro).
Even tough I am a JS noob I managed to find and edit scripts until I got pretty much the perfect [script](http://jsfiddle.net/L78zh/)

Problem is that the sliding panels are closing when clicked outside. I want then to close when another panel opens but not when somebody clicks outside the panel.

Also this will be an one page design except the portfolio. I a link to index.html with the portfolio panel open. Can I do that? To understand better what I mean please check this [image](http://design-way.ro/images/hoveralls/portfolio_single.jpg).

Edit: Okay I will explain better.

This will be a one page design, since I will be using sliding panels for pages. However each gallery item will have it's own html page because I do not want the site to be slow.

So I need to link portfolioitem1.html to the index.html with the portfolio panel open just like in the image I posted

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow the second part of your question, in the final paragraph. Can you explain or, perhaps, rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsFiddle that solves the first part of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/aUHwA/1/

The thing that was causing the panels to collapse was the `document.click()` function you were using. I've moved everything into a `$(document).ready()` function, added some generic wrappers for the sliders and buttons, and used a generic click function that's shared across all three buttons.

The click function uses the `data-rel` property of the button that was clicked to decide what panel it should toggle. It also hides any panels that are already visible within the `#content` div.

To open the portfolio panel by default, you can add this immediately after the on('click') function:

```
$('#portfolio_button').click();
```

That will trigger the portfolio animation (see http://jsfiddle.net/aUHwA/3/). Alternatively:

```
$('#portfolio').slideToggle(0);
```

will open the portfolio panel instantly, without the sliding animation (see http://jsfiddle.net/aUHwA/2/).